# How to find number of edges in a graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let G(V,E) be an **undirected** graph:

$$V={\{0,1\}}^n$$

E:
There is an edge between A and B iff, A and B differ in **exactly one** index

For example (when n=4 -which is the length of each world-):

There is an edge connecting `0000,0001` and another edge connecting `0100,0110` But, there is no edge connecting `0000,1010`

I need to find the number of edges in this graph

I proved that each vertices is connected to n other vertices

Comment: @AnuragA You should make that comment an answer.  It's a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of vertices is $2^n$ and each vertex (according to you) is adjacent to $n$ other vertices. So the total degree is  $2^n \,n$. So the number of edges will be half of it as each edge will be counted twice.

Comment: But may you explain why it is half? that's were I'm struggling

Comment: @Daniel98 I have mentioned that too (see the solution). Think of it this way: we both shake our hands. When someone asks me, I will say I shook one hand and you will say the same, so is the number of handshakes $2$? No because we both counted the same handshake twice. Thus the total number of handshakes is just $1$.

Comment: great explanation, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A second solution for completeness:

Select one of the dimensions where the difference occurs. There are $\binom{n}{1} = n$ choices. The other dimensions can be anything else but they have to be identical. Each remaining dimension has $2$ choices, giving $2^{n-1}$ choices. The final total is $n2^{n-1}$.

The graph described is an **$n$-dimensional hypercube**. This counting method extends very well into finding the number of faces, cells, $4$-cells, etc. of the hypercube as well.